# Avoid blank line at end of file when using writeLines

Tags: r, text

In R: Is it possible to avoid having a blank line at the end of a text file generated by writeLines? If not, is there any other way of generating a text file from within R without having a blank line at the end?

Comment: So do you not want the last line to end with a newline character? Is that what you mean by blank line? What code are you actually running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no blank line.

R (correctly) ends each line with `'\n'` (or `'\r\n'` on Windows). In other words, the file consists of lines, and each line ends with a line break.

Unfortunately, there are many tools (especially on Windows) which treat such files incorrectly and display an extra line at the end. However, that’s a fault with these tools, not with R. Consequently, this shouldn’t be fixed in the R code.

As a hack to appease buggy tools, the only recourse is to set the `sep` argument of `writeLines` to the empty string, `''`, and insert the line breaks *between* lines manually (using `paste`).

Comment: Thanks, now I understand, the recourse solved the issue for me: `fileConn <- file("mytext.txt")

writeLines(paste(c("line1", "line2", "line3"), collapse="\n"), sep="", fileConn)

close(fileConn)`

Comment: @user3298179 Hm, I was very reluctant to add the last paragraph to my answer, because **you should *not* do this**. The whole point of my answer was that R already does the correct thing, and your new code does the wrong thing.

Comment: For my specific purpose I HAD to do it this way. I generated sh-files for the purpose of starting R scripts on a Sun Grid Engine. When having a line break at the end of the last line they threw errors. So I agree that this is not the right way to do it, but the recourse can be useful for specific purposes.

Comment: since I had your problem and your workaround did not work for me, @user3298179, I added an answer that is cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same concern (different grid, though) and even your comment of the accept answer (by Konrad) did not work for me.

I found the answer   [here](https://ubccr.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/13000041215-how-to-fix-sbatch-error-batch-script-contains-dos-line-breaks-), and here is the full code:

```
fileConn = file("mytext.txt")
writeLines(c("line1", "line2", "line3"), sep="\n", fileConn)

#now connect to UNIX server and upload your file
library(ssh)
session=ssh_connect("user@server.com")
scp_upload(session, files="mytext.txt")

#Here is the trick, convert all the Windows extra chars to unix
ssh_exec_wait(session, command="dos2unix mytext.txt")

#Then start your Grid job
ssh_exec_wait(session, command="sbatch mytext.txt")

ssh_disconnect(session)
```

Comment: That fixes a *different issue* than OP’s, namely the fact that Windows files contain different line separators than Unix files. My answer *definitely works* and fixes OP’s issue. And for what it’s worth there’s absolutely no need to use an external tool to fix that — you can do that directly in R, you just need to write a *binary* file rather than a text file (pass `mode = 'wb'` to `file`). That’s *much less* convoluted than what you’re suggesting.

Comment: Well, you said "R (correctly) ends each line with '\n' (or '\r\n' on Windows). In other words, the file consists of lines, and each line ends with a line break.". This is the buggy behavior: even though you clearly specify that sep="\n" in writeLines, you end up with \r\n using R on Windows. It does not make sense. Also, "writing a binary file" might be the answer, but is not part of your initial reply.

Comment: “It does not make sense” — Actually it makes perfect sense, it’s *expected behaviour* for text connections to convert between `'\n'` and the system newline, and contrary to your comment *it’s not buggy*. I didn’t mention how to convert Windows line endings since that was not part of OP’s question. My answer only mentions them in passing, and for completeness; but they’re really unrelated to what OP asked. It’s a separate question.